# crashing when erasing in a map (C++)

Tags: c++, stl

Here is a part of code that is crashed always. I can't understand the reason of this crash. All I do is set some pointers in a loop. If I comment this cycle all will be OK. It's strange.. The code in the bottom is where the crash happend. I can't get what destructor is called and why my program is crahsing.

```
    typedef std::set<IDrawable**> TDrawableList;
        typedef std::map<std::string, TDrawableList> THashLoad;
//  ...
    THashLoad::iterator itLoad =  gpMapRenderer->m_unloadedCells.find(file.substr(6, file.length()));
        if (itLoad != gpMapRenderer->m_unloadedCells.end())
        {
                TDrawableList::iterator itCells = itLoad->second.begin();
                TDrawableList::iterator itCellsEnd = itLoad->second.end();
                for (; itCells != itCellsEnd; ++itCells)
                {
                        **itCells = (IDrawable*)itHashPics->second.pImg;
                }

                gpMapRenderer->m_unloadedCells.erase(itLoad);  // < --- CRASH
        }
    // ... 
    // _construct.h
    // ...
template <class _Tp>
inline void _Destroy(_Tp* __pointer) {
# if _MSC_VER >= 1010
  __pointer;
# endif    // _MSC_VER >= 1000
# ifdef _STLP_TRIVIAL_DESTRUCTOR_BUG
  typedef typename __type_traits<_Tp>::has_trivial_destructor _Trivial_destructor;
  __destroy_aux(__pointer, _Trivial_destructor());
# else
#  if ( defined (__BORLANDC__) && ( __BORLANDC__ < 0x500 ) )
    __pointer->_Tp::~_Tp();
#  else
    __pointer->~_Tp(); // < ---- CRASH
#  endif
# endif
# ifdef _STLP_DEBUG_UNINITIALIZED
        memset((char*)__pointer, _STLP_SHRED_BYTE, sizeof(_Tp));
# endif
}
```

P.S. My program is single-threaded.

Thank you.

Update:

```
class IDrawable
{
public:
    virtual ~IDrawable() {};

    virtual void Draw(const CIwSVec2& pos) = 0;
    virtual void Draw(const CIwSVec2& pos, const CIwSVec2& size) { IwAssert(IDRAWABLE, "Not Implemented");};
};
```

So here is how I add to m_unloadedCells:

```
void MapRenderer::AddCellToUnloadedList(const std::string& filename, IDrawable** pElement)
{
    THashLoad::iterator itLoad = m_unloadedCells.find(filename);
    if (itLoad != m_unloadedCells.end())
        itLoad->second.insert(pElement);
    else
    {
        std::set<IDrawable**> _set;
        _set.insert(pElement);
        m_unloadedCells.insert(make_pair(filename, _set));
    }
}
```

and somewhere in the code:

```
AddCellToUnloadedList(filenameToLoad, &itHashCells->second[index].drawingElement[i].pDrawable)
```

itHashcells:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::vector<Cell2> > THashCells;
THashCells itHashCells;
```

Cell2:

```
enum eDrawableType
{
    DTYPE_Sprite = 0,
    DTYPE_Animation
};

struct DrawingElement
{
    eDrawableType type;
    IDrawable* pDrawable;
};

struct Cell2
{
    Cell2()
    {
        drawingElement.reserve(10);
    }

    int location;
    int x, y;

    std::vector<DrawingElement> drawingElement;

    MinimapTileInfo minimap_tile_info[10];
};
```

Comment: Please don't link us to an external site whose code may be gone in a few days / months. Also "everyone!" is entirely unnecessary. We know who this is for.

Comment: Does `IDrawable` have a `trivial_destructor` ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know now how to put some code into the comments here, I'll upgrade it in the topic

Comment: Can you create a compilable example that shows your problem? I can't use this code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Looks like memory corrupted somewhere else and erase method not the reason. How elements of gpMapRenderer->m_unloadedCells are initialized?

Comment: @TonyTheLion I think it will be difficult for me to do that.

Comment: @Slava is it possible to add here additional code ? I'm not sure how to do that. It's my first post here on stackoverflow.. So I'm a little embarassed..

Comment: At the bottom of your post, above the comments, on the left, there are four buttons: `share | edit | close | flag`. Just click `edit` and add the new code to your question.

Comment: @Beta Thank you, but I thougt I'm able to add that into comments )

Comment: @PaveL explain types for &itHashCells->second[index].drawingElement[i].pDrawable

Comment: I am seeing rather a lot of pointers. Why set<IDrawable**> ?

Comment: @CashCow You see my pictures are not loaded at once.. And it is loaded from the internet.. So I keep pointers to pointers and when some picture is loaded I just update pointers inside and this picture will be drawn. I know that it would be better to use some pattern like Observer, but this is needed for a small group of images so I decided to do this in such way.

Comment: The C cast here obfuscates things: `**itCells = (IDrawable*)itHashPics->second.pImg;` What happens if you don't cast at all? If this doesn't compile there is probably something wrong with your code.

Comment: What is itHashPics? And why is there a global map called itHashCells ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be in this line:

```
**itCells = (IDrawable*)itHashPics->second.pImg;
```

not in erase(). Try to comment it out and see.
I think issue is you initialize pointers to data structure that inside 2 vectors, though I see that you reserve 10 elements in Cell2 it is not clear if you do not have more than 10 elements in it or reserve enough in itHashCells. So if you insert enough elements into any of that vector to make them reallocate space that invalidates your pointers in gpMapRenderer->m_unloadedCells

I would suggest to take time and refactor your code, trying to avoid using pointer to pointer, or at least use data structure that would not invalidate them. Code in current state is unmantainable.

Also you can rewrite this code:

```
void MapRenderer::AddCellToUnloadedList(const std::string& filename, IDrawable** pElement)
{
    THashLoad::iterator itLoad = m_unloadedCells.find(filename);
    if (itLoad != m_unloadedCells.end())
        itLoad->second.insert(pElement);
    else
    {
        std::set<IDrawable**> _set;
        _set.insert(pElement);
        m_unloadedCells.insert(make_pair(filename, _set));
    }
}
```

as this:

```
void MapRenderer::AddCellToUnloadedList(const std::string& filename, IDrawable** pElement)
{
    m_unloadedCells[ filename ].insert( pElement );
}
```

I think it is more readable and at least as effective as original.

Comment: Thank you. I'll make some refactoring. May be something will become clear.